# Colocar suma y media en las columnas 6 y 7 matriz (JAVA)

Tags: java, array

Tengo que sacar una matriz de 7x5 por pantalla y a continuación sacar otra de 7x7 con las primeras 5 columnas iguales que la matriz anterior.
En la sexta columna colocar la suma de las 5 columnas anteriores y en la séptima columna la media de las primeras 5 columnas anteriores.

si no me equivoco seria algo asi:

```
1 2 3 4 5 15 3
1 2 3 4 5 15 3
1 2 3 4 5 15 3
1 2 3 4 5 15 3
1 2 3 4 5 15 3
1 2 3 4 5 15 3
1 2 3 4 5 15 3

Esto sería:
15 = 1+2+3+4+5
3 = 15 / 5
```

Yo tengo este codigo, creo que me acerco al resultado pero no logro verlo correctamente.

```
    public class Matriz {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k, l,i,j = 0;

    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

    //primera matriz 7x5
    int matriz[][]=new int [7][5];
    System.out.println("Introduce un numero");
    int num = lector.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Esta es tu matriz de 7x5: ");
    for (i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = num + i;
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    //segunda matriz 7x7
    int matriz2[][]=new int [7][7];


    System.out.println("\nEsta es tu matriz de 7x7: \n*Las 5 primeras columnas son iguales a tu anterior matriz.\n*La sexta columna"
            + " muestra la suma de las 5 primeras filas y columnas de la matriz.\n*La septima columna muestra la media de las 5 primeras columnas y filas.\n");

    int sexta,suma = 0,media=0;

    for (k = 0; k < matriz2.length; k++) {
        for (l = 0; l < matriz2[k].length; l++) {
            matriz2[k][l] = num + k;
        }
    }

            for (i = 0; i < matriz.length;i ++) {
                for (j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {                        
                    suma = suma + matriz[i][j];
                    media = suma/5;
                    matriz2[i][5]=suma;
                    matriz2[i][6]=media;
                    suma=0;                     
                }
            }

     for (k=0; k!=matriz2.length;k++) {
     matriz2[k][5]=suma;
     matriz2[k][6]=media;
     }

    for (k = 0; k < matriz2.length; k++) {
        for (l = 0; l < matriz2[k].length; l++) {
            System.out.print(matriz2[k][l]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Explico:
Primero pido al usuario que introduzca un numero, a partir de este numero se crean los arrays de 7x5, que se enseña por pantalla y el de 7x7 que se enseña a continuación, acto seguido , hago la suma y la media de las filas y columnas, aunque creo que debería de hacer la suma y la media fila por fila de las 5 primeras columnas, pero no se muy bien como hacerlo.
Después intento asignarle a la posición de la columna 6 la suma y a la posición 7 la media y con un for trato de enseñar el resultado.

Lo que sale por pantalla:

```
Introduce un numero
4
Esta es tu matriz de 7x5: 
4 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 
6 6 6 6 6 
7 7 7 7 7 
8 8 8 8 8 
9 9 9 9 9 
10 10 10 10 10 

Esta es tu matriz de 7x7: 
*Las 5 primeras columnas son iguales a tu anterior matriz.
*La sexta columna muestra la suma de las 5 primeras filas y columnas de la matriz.
*La septima columna muestra la media de las 5 primeras columnas y filas.

4 4 4 4 4 0 2 
5 5 5 5 5 0 2 
6 6 6 6 6 0 2 
7 7 7 7 7 0 2 
8 8 8 8 8 0 2 
9 9 9 9 9 0 2 
10 10 10 10 10 0 2
```

Alguna orientación , idea o ayuda sobre que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Te dice que estás fuera de los límites de la matriz y es verdad porque la matriz va de 0 a 6 nunca llega a 7

Comment: si coloco matriz2[k][1]=suma; me sigue dando error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El programa lo tienes casi hecho, el problema radica en esta línea:

```
matriz2[k][6]=suma;
matriz2[k][7]=media;
```

Pero antes de entender el porqué, analicemos este bloque de código:

```
for (k = 0; k < matriz2.length; k++) {
    for (l = 0; l < matriz2[k].length; l++) {
       matriz2[k][l] = num + k;
       System.out.print(matriz2[k][l]+" ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Si te das cuenta, la variable `k` se quedará con el valor que tenga `matriz2.length` (en este caso `k = 7`).

Entonces, volvamos a este código:

```
matriz2[k][6]=suma;
```

Si la variable `k` vale `7`, estarías provocando un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer), pero como el [JVM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_virtual_Java) nunca dejará que ocurra el desbordamiento, te lanzará la excepción [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) y esto hará que tu programa deje de funcionar.

**¿Por qué me dio esta excepción?**

La respuesta es sencilla, tu matriz es de `7x7`, es decir, solo acepta 7 filas y 7 columnas, pero solo puedes indexar de `0 a 6`, si te pasas del índice máximo que es `6`, ocurrirá la excepción.

Lo mismo pasa en esta línea:

```
matriz2[k][7]=media;
```

En la segunda indexación, agregaste un `7`, pero solo se puede indexar hasta 6 (porqué el tamaño de columnas es 7).

**Solución:**

```
for(k = 0; k != matriz2.length; ++k)
{
    matriz2[k][5]=suma;
    matriz2[k][6] = media;
}
```

El código lo que hace es recorrer fila por fila y asignar la suma y la media en la penúltima y última columna, respectivamente.

**EDIT:**

El último for sobrescribirá los valores de la matriz:

```
     System.out.println(suma);
     System.out.println(media);

     for (k=0; k!=matriz2.length;k++) {
     matriz2[k][5]=suma;
     matriz2[k][6]=media;
     }
    //Este for hará que tu programa no muestre el resultado esperado...
    for (k = 0; k < matriz2.length; k++) {
        for (l = 0; l < matriz2[k].length; l++) {
            matriz2[k][l] = num + k; //elimina esta línea..
            System.out.print(matriz2[k][5]+" "); 
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Debes reemplazar estas dos líneas:

```
matriz2[k][l] = num + k;
System.out.print(matriz2[k][5]+" ");
```

Por esta:

```
System.out.print(matriz2[k][l]+" ");
```

Por último, para poder sumar los valores por fila y obtener su media para después agregarlo en la sexta y séptima columna, respectivamente, lo harías de esta forma:

```
for (i = 0; i < matriz.length; i ++) 
{
       for (j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) 
       //Obtenemos la suma de X fila
            suma = suma + matriz[i][j];
        //Obtenemos la media
        media = suma / 5;
        //Asignamos la suma en la sexta columna
        matriz2[i][5] = suma;
        //Asignamos la media en la séptima columna
        matriz2[i][6] = media;
        suma = 0;
}
```

**SEGUNDA EDICIÓN:**

Has agregado mal el siguiente código:

```
suma = suma + matriz[i][j];
media = suma/5;
matriz2[i][5]=suma;
matriz2[i][6]=media;
suma=0;
```

Lo único que va adentro del bucle anidado es lo siguiente:

```
suma = suma + matriz[i][j];
```

**¿Por qué debe ir adentro?**
La respuesta es sencilla, porqué el bucle anidado se encargará de ir sumando columna x columna por fila. Después que termine de ejecutarse, se procede a calcular la media, por esa razón, el siguiente código debería ir afuera del bucle anidado:

```
media = suma/5;
matriz2[i][5]=suma;
matriz2[i][6]=media;
suma=0;
```

El código completo quedaría así:

```
import java.util.*;

public class prueba 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int k, l,i,j = 0;
        int sexta, suma = 0, media = 0;
        int [][]matriz2;
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        //primera matriz 7x5
        int [][]matriz =new int [7][5];
        System.out.println("Introduce un numero");
        int num = lector.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Esta es tu matriz de 7x5: ");
        for (i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) 
        {
            for (j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) 
            {
                matriz[i][j] = num + i;
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }


        //segunda matriz 7x7
        matriz2 =new int [7][7];

        for (k = 0; k < matriz2.length; k++) 
        {
            for (l = 0; l < matriz2[k].length; l++) 
                matriz2[k][l] = num + k;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) 
        {
            for (j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++)                   
                suma = suma + matriz[i][j];                  
            media = suma/5;
            matriz2[i][5]=suma;
            matriz2[i][6]=media;
            suma=0;    
        }

        for (k = 0; k < matriz2.length; k++)
        {
            for (l = 0; l < matriz2[k].length; l++) 
                System.out.print(matriz2[k][l]+" ");
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola muchisimas gracias!!! ahora el error ya no me sale y parece que funciona bien, pero no termino de aclararme con la duda que tenia antes, de colocar en la columna 6 y 7 la suma y la media, he modificado mi pregunta, con tu corrección ahora saldría así. Si en vez de sumar las 5 columnas y filas enteras y colocar el resultado que es 210 en este caso y 6 que es la media quisiera sumar fila por fila y colocar en la 6 y séptima posición el resultado por fila, como sería?

Comment: @azucarilla No te había entendido bien, he actualizado mi respuesta de nuevo, espero que te sirva.

Comment: Disculpa la molestia :( pero creo que el resultado no me va bien o he puesto yo mal algo, he editado el código de la pregunta y el resultado por pantalla.

Comment: @azucarilla Acabé de editar mi respuesta por segunda vez. Espero que esta vez si te funcione :) .

Comment: ah vale vale, ya comprendo. Joo, muchas gracias por tomarte un tiempo en ayudarme! estoy muy agradecida! Estoy saturada creo ya con esta clase de ejercicios los saco, pero creo que me mareo y no logro ver los resultados.